# Copy files from host to Docker container without using Docker command

Tags: java, docker

Is there any way to copy files from the host to Docker container without using **Docker `cp` command**?

I am developing a web project using Java. In that I need to download a file from the web and copy that file to my Docker container.

How can I do it without using Docker `cp` command?

Comment: Have you looked at docker volumes?

Comment: @MargachChris No, I don't about that, Can you explain shortly?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this link. Let me know if it works for you http://docs.docker.oeynet.com/machine/reference/scp/#example

Comment: Sorry, Here in my project, I need to download a file from web and send to my container.